# LINQ Lambda: Getting Last item (where == ) of sub collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following (which I've used in CodeFirst):

```
public class MyForm
    {
        public int MyFormId { get; set; }
        //Many Form Properties
        public virtual ICollection<AuditItem> AuditItems { get; set; }
    }

public class AuditItem
    {
        public int AuditItemId { get; set; }
        public int MyFormId { get; set; }
        public IAppUser User { get; set; }
        public string ActionByUserStr { get; set; }
        public string ActionByUserDisplayName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfAction { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfAction { get; set; }
        public int Step { get; set; }

        public virtual MyForm MyForm { get; set; }
    }
```

The AuditItem tracks many actions carried out on MyForm

I'm presenting an index page showing a table where the AuditItem's last Step = 1.

I do an orderby DateOfAction (because the Step can get setback to 0, so I wouldn't want it to equal 1 unless it is also the last AuditItem Record for that MyForm), then Select the last record's step, then query on that.  I want to query as early as I can so that I'm not pulling back unrequired MyForms records.

This is the query I have:

```
var myFormsAtStep1 =
                context.MyForms.Include("AuditItems").Where(
                    mf => mf.AuditItems.OrderBy(ai => ai.DateOfAction).Last().Step == 1);
```

It gives this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MyForms.Models.AuditItem Last[AuditItem](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyForms.Models.AuditItem])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to order descending, then take the first item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the list of [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx).

`Last()` is not supported, but `First()` is, so you can just go on and reverse your ordering and use `First()` instead of `Last()`.

```
mf => mf.AuditItems.OrderByDescending(ai => ai.DateOfAction).First().Step == 1);
```

Comment: Using First() worked, I stuck with a lambda version.  
Accepted this answer as it came first and sorted my issue, both were correct.

Answer (score 2):

You simply sort in descending order and get the first item.

```
var myFormsAtStep1 =
    context.MyForms.Include("AuditItems").Where(
        mf => mf.AuditItems.OrderByDescending(
            ai => ai.DateOfAction).First().Step == 1);
```

I would also use the query syntax, which would be more readable, as well as the strongly-typed Include (import System.Data.Entity):

```
from mf in context.MyForms.Include(x => x.AuditItems)
let items = from ai in mf.AuditItems
            orderby ai.DateOfAction descending
            select ai;
where items.First().Step == 1
select mf
```

Comment: You would also need to work around `Reverse()` not being supported in the same way, by reversing the sort direction, but that is rarely seen.

Comment: This also fixed my issue, I accepted the other answer as it came first. Many thanks.